# Openmeeting join room doesn't work

Tags: openmeetings

I have created room and joining it from following url

http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/hash?secure=609a1015-030e-430b-8eb3-b7aa6fe74980&language=1

But it is not working properly. I am getting screen as shown in image below.
[image]

My openmeeting version is 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you have created secure hash for recording, not for room (you have provided recordingId)

To create room hash do not specify recordingId in options.

Comment: Okay! It works. But What have to do if I want to record room session.

Comment: To record room session you have to use recording functionality inside the room (after entering). This is the button 'Start recording' in interview rooms and 'Screen-sharing web-application' in other rooms